# How to get output for every cpu percentage

Tags: linux

```
for i in  `cat servers.txt` ; do
   for k in `cat ip.txt` ; do
      cpu=`sshpass -f passfile ssh $i -p 8022 "sshpass -p admin ssh $k "top -n 1 | grep /system/bin/mediaserver | a
wk '{print $8*100}'""`
          echo " The cpu percentage of $k is $cpu" > file
   done
done
```

When I run the script to save the output in a file variable `k` has two IP addresses, but in `file` it is only saving the last IP address. I want to get two IP addresses output in file.

Comment: ``$cpu" > file`` should read ``$cpu >> file``

Comment: echo "hi" | ssmtp 123456@gmail.com how to add subject to send mail